# How can this AnyObject? has boolValue property

Tags: swift

I have written an NSURL extension in Swift.

```
extension NSURL {
  var isDir : Bool {
    do {
      var isDir : AnyObject?
      try self.getResourceValue(&isDir, forKey: NSURLIsDirectoryKey)
      if let result = isDir?.boolValue {
        return result
      } else {
        return false
      }
    } catch {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

That works. But I find some people "cast" the pointer (`isDIR` in this case) to `NSNumber` first. Examples are:

- [NSFileManager list directory contents excluding directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028267/nsfilemanager-list-directory-contents-excluding-directories)
- [NSURL getResourceValue in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24400276/nsurl-getresourcevalue-in-swift)

I've found no documentation says `AnyObject` conforms to the `BooleanType` protocol. So how does my code in Swift work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-click on `AnyObject` and you will find the answer:

```
/// The protocol to which all classes implicitly conform.
///
/// When used as a concrete type, all known `@objc` methods and
/// properties are available, as implicitly-unwrapped-optional methods
/// and properties respectively, on each instance of `AnyObject`.  For
/// example:
///
///     class C {
///       @objc func getCValue() -> Int { return 42 }
///     }
///
///     // If x has a method @objc getValue()->Int, call it and
///     // return the result.  Otherwise, return nil.
///     func getCValue1(x: AnyObject) -> Int? {
///       if let f: ()->Int = x.getCValue { // <===
///         return f()
///       }
///       return nil
///     }
///
///     // A more idiomatic implementation using "optional chaining"
///     func getCValue2(x: AnyObject) -> Int? {
///       return x.getCValue?() // <===
///     }
///
///     // An implementation that assumes the required method is present
///     func getCValue3(x: AnyObject) -> Int { // <===
///       return x.getCValue() // x.getCValue is implicitly unwrapped. // <===
///     }
///
/// - SeeAlso: `AnyClass`
@objc public protocol AnyObject {
}
```

So, you can call any @objc method on an `AnyObject` instance.

If you type

```
let a: AnyObject?
```

in a Playground and then:

```
a?.
```

autocomplete will show you the complete list of methods you can call.  And it is **huge**.

Comment: You can skip the casts.  Just be sure to use optional binding because `nil` will be returned if the method doesn't exist for the underlying object type.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case, if `isDir` is not `nil`, it must be an `NSNumber`, right? Also `(isDir as? NSNumber)?.boolValue` has a cast and an unwrapping, may it be less efficient?

Comment: You might still want to write it like `if let result = (isDir as? NSNumber)?.boolValue {` because it documents to your reader what you expect to be happening, but functionally you can skip the cast.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for `getResourceValue(_ *value*:forKey:)` indicates that `_ *value*:` is an `AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject?>` type, which means it is fundamentally a void pointer which can be cast to any type so long as it is a proper type.  Therefore, the direct cast of `isDir` to a `Bool` will work because that is basically what it is, a Boolean type:

```
let boolResult: Bool = isDir as! Bool
```

simply works as a direct cast because it is a void type to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to vacawama's answer, the Swift documentation is worded in a slightly confusing way. It says that for `AnyObject`

> `@objc` symbols are available as implicitly unwrapped optional methods and
> properties, respectively.

You might think this means everything is implicitly unwrapped, but that's not true. The *methods* are available as implicitly unwrapped optionals, but the *properties* types are all available as optionals. So while it is in generally unsafe to call a method on an `AnyObject`, it is safe to access a property.

For example,

```
let str = "Hello!" as NSString
let any = str as AnyObject
str.firstObject // compiler error, firstObject is an NSArray property
any.firstObject // nil
```

This is why you can safely call `boolValue`. It gets imported from `NSNumber` and its type is changed to `Bool?`.